# Options button on Android Devices since version 6, Menu inflating

Tags: android

In my app, I have `onCreateOptionsMenu` which inflates a menu that contains "contact" and "about" (information about the developer etc). I currently have a device with 5.0 Lollipop. On this device, when you press at "options"(beside of the back button) you can see the menu inflating. But on my other device with Android 6.0 pressing on "options" opens just the stack of running applications in the background, like a TaskManager. So the user has to press the 3 dots on the `ActionBar` to see the menu inflating.

Can I change that? Or is there anything to fix that in order to make it easy for the user to see this menu inflating by not pressing on the 3 dots in the `ActionBar` because on large devices this is toilsome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I currently have a device with 5.0 Lollipop. On this device, when you press at "options"(beside of the back button) you can see the menu inflating.

Either that device was upgraded to Android 5.0 from Android 4.3, or that device is not in compliance with the Compatibility Definition Document (e.g., it is not a Google Play ecosystem device).

> But on my other device with Android 6.0 pressing on "options" opens just the stack of running applications in the background, like a TaskManager.

That's because there is no MENU button on devices that ship with Android 4.4+. The button that took its place is a RECENTS button, for showing the overview screen (i.e., recently-used tasks).

> Can I change that?

No.

> Or is there anything to fix that in order to make it easy for the user to see this menu inflating by not pressing on the 3 dots in the ActionBar because on large devices this is toilsome.

No. If you do not like the behavior of the action bar overflow menu, do not use it.

Comment: Well, thank you that was a pretty clear answer. I appreciate this :D